# Modifying an 3D image in mhd format using Python

Tags: python, simpleitk

I have a MR image volume in *.mhd format, and I do not have access to the original DICOM file. The image is not square and I need to crop the image and save a new *.mhd file again. I have a *.json file which contains all information of the original DICOM header.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a example that shows how to crop an image in SimpleITK to get a square sub-image:

```
import random
import SimpleITK as sitk

img = sitk.Image(random.randrange(100,200), random.randrange(100,200), sitk.sitkUInt8)

size = img.GetSize()
print(size)

min_size = min(size[0], size[1])

# using python slicing to extract a sub-image
cropped_img = img[0:min_size, 0:min_size]

print(cropped_img.GetSize())
sitk.WriteImage(cropped_img, "square.mhd")
```

Note that the section being cropped is at the "end" (high index values) of the image.